# Control type as datatype of datacolumn

Tags: c#, types, datacolumn

I've done this in vb.net, but can't seem to get it to work in `c#`. I'm trying to set the `datatype` of a new `datacolumn` to Label (or System.Windows.Forms.Label) so that this datatable can have references to controls on the form for faster indexing. Code snippet:

```
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn {DataType = System.Windows.Forms.Label, ColumnName = "labelDate"};
```

is throwing error "'Label' is a type, which is not valid in the given context". Meanwhile, "DataType" requires "Type", so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Note, I've also tried "DataType = Type.GetType(Label)" as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, leaving the answer here in case it's helpful to anyone

```
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn {DataType = typeof(Label), ColumnName = "labelDate"};
```